# Notify user when wcf service is stopped in windows phone 7

Tags: asp.net, wcf, windows-phone-7

I have a windows phone 7 app which uses a wcf service in some events. I need to notify the app user when the service is temporary not available. ie. the user should be prompted with appropriate msg to try after sometime or so and the app should work with the cashed data. I tried to use the code:

```
public static Boolean isSiteOnline(String url)
{
    Boolean result = true;
    HttpWebRequest httpReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    httpReq.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    HttpWebResponse httpRes = (HttpWebResponse)httpReq.GetResponse();
    if (httpRes.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        result = false;

    httpRes.Close();
    return result;
}
```

But in Windows phone 7 am not able to get the function GetResponse()[Ln 6]. Is there any namespace that am missing? or is there any other way out?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone does not support many synchroneous functions. `GetResponse` is one of them.

You sould use asynchronous version - `BeginGetResponse`

Sample can be found here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(VS.95).aspx